# An error pops up whenever i run my android project on Android Studio in Windows 8.1

Tags: android, windows

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\SDK\build-tools\22.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Projects\Projects-Android\JetFighters\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\Projects\Projects-Android\JetFighters\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Comment: Try once clean the project ,if still error post your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are including a library multiple times in your project. Check you gradle file for dependencies you have used. After modifying the gradle file to remove duplicate library, do a gradle sync and build the workspace. I have fixed same issue using this approach recently.